# ¿Cómo hacer un mapeo dentro de otro mapeo en react?

Tags: reactjs

Buen día tengo un 2 funciones que me devuelven 2 estados diferentes los cuales quiero mapear en una tabla. mi problema es que no se como hacer un mapeo dentro de otro.

Actualmente tengo asi mi codigo en la tabla:

```
<tbody>
      {
         this.state.datas.map((item, _index) => {
          //let mostrar_input = (item.first_name != '') ? true : false;
               return (
                 <tr key={item.iddef_type_room_relations} id={"tr" + item.hotel_description}>
                                        {/* Resort */}
                                        <td><a to="chart" target="_blank" href="https://www.palaceproagents.com" className="text-main text-capitalize">{item.hotel_description}</a></td>
                                        {/* Check-in */}
                                        <td><DateFormat date={item.arrival_date}/></td>
                                        {/* Check-out */}
                                        <td><DateFormat date={item.departure_date}/></td>
                                        {/* Duration */}
                                        <td>{item.nigths} nights</td>
                                        {
                                            this.state.count.map((item, index) => {
                                                return(
                                                    {/* Total Rooms On */}
                                            <td>
                                                <th>{item.estado1}</th>
                                                <th>{item.estado2}</th>
                                                <th>{item.estado3}</th>
                                            </td>
                                            )
                                            })
                                        }
                                        {/* Room type */}
                                        <td><a to="chart" className="text-main text-capitalize" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{item.room_type_description}</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

Lo cual no funciona. 
Agradeceria mucho me ayudaran y quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Hola Luis, de pronto podriamos ofrecerte una mejor respuesta si sabemos que hay dentro de tu `state` de esa forma podemos saber qué objetos son arreglos para aplicar el ´map´ o la iteración y cuales no

Comment: Pues de hecho cada state es una arreglo en si por ejemplo  el estado `datas:{iddef_type_room_relations: 4, arrival_date: 4, departure_date: 4, nigths: 4,  etc.}` y `count:{estado1: 2, estado2: 2, estado3: 2}`.

Comment: `{/* Total Rooms On */}` no debería ir. Eso es error de sintaxis, ya que no se pueden retornar etiquetas adyacentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar un .MAP dentro de otro lo puedes hacer de esta manera, te pongo como ejemplo para sacar todas las subcategorias de todas las categorias de una web.

Ejemplo de un objeto de categorías de subcategorias.

```
this.state = {
  categories: [
    {
      name: "Consolas",
      subcategories: [
        {
          name: "PS4"
        },
        {
          name: "Xbox"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        name: "Videojuegos",
        subcategories: [
          {
            name: "PS4"
          },
          {
            name: "Xbox"
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
};
```

Bucle con .MAP

```
{categories.map((category, categoryIndex) => {
    const subcategories = category;

    {subcategories.map((subcategory, subcataegoryIndex) => (
        <span key={subcataegoryIndex}>
            {subcategory.name}
        </span>
      ))}
    );
})}
```